# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' while Migrating application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS Code for developing .Net Core  RTM web api . While I am running command `dotnet ef migrations add "myfirstMigraion"` for migration then getting error which is attached as Image below. :-
[image]
My project.json file looks like :-

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions":"1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    // "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":"1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "firstCoreApi"
  }
}
```

And looks like my Startup.cs :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using firstCoreApi.Model;
namespace firstCoreApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=myPcName\SQLEXPRESS; Database=StudentsDB;user id=MysqlUserId;password=Mysqlpassword;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            //Server=SQLSERVERNAME;Database=StudentsDB;user id=sa;password=sa1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            //  services.AddDbContext<TodoListDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());
            services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Operating system Windows 10 with sql server 2014. I need your help folks how to fixed it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also appeared the same Exception, I just "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0-rc2-final" changed to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0".it's work

I think If you use VSCODE, you can try changes to in the project.json

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.  Install the package from the command line.  Website for help: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kendo.Mvc/2016.2.630-Preview

The command to use in the package manager: Install-Package Kendo.Mvc -Pre

The package that NuGet returns from searches is the latest stable package, which contains the bug, lol!  That is why you need to install from the command line in the package manager.

Telerik knows about the issue: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1856

Comment: Spot on! If you get the error while trying to load the kendo service to the asp.net startup, this is the solution. Thanks a lot man!